# Regex pattern for mobile number validation with extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have seperate regex validations for my requirement but struggling to combine them in one.
I am validation mobile numbers with country code or starting with 00 and also if they contain extension number(2-5 digits) seperated by #

Following is the example of valid Number :

```
+919986040933
00919986040933
+919986040933#12
+919986040933#123
+919986040933#1234
+919986040933#12345
```

I have following regex to validate the above:

```
var phoneRegexWithPlus = "^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{10,14}$";
var phoneRegexWithZero = "^((\\+)|(00))[0-9]{9,12}$";
var phoneRegexExtension = "^[0-9]{2,5}$";
```

Currently i am checking whether number contains #,if yes then split it and match number and extension part seperately where extension is comething after hash.

My problem is now that i have to create one regex combining the above three,can anyone help me with that as m not good in regex.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like [this?](https://regex101.com/r/rQ5nN9/2)

Comment: `(?:\+91|00)\d{10}(?:#\d{2,5})?`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this expression:

```
^\+?(?:00)?\d{12}(?:#\d{2,5})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bN0gH1/1)

**Expression explanation**:

- `^` - start of string
- `\+?` - an optional plus (as `?` matches the `+` one or zero times)
- `(?:00)?` - an optional `00`
- `\d{12}` - Exactly 12 digit string
- `(?:#\d{2,5})?` - an optional (again, `?` matches one or zero times) sequence of:

  - `#` - a literal hash symbol
  - `\d{2,5}` - 2 to 5 digits (your ***`phoneRegexExtension`***)
- `$` - end of string.

The ***`phoneRegexWithPlus`*** and ***`phoneRegexWithZero`*** are covered with the first obligatory part `\+?(?:00)?\d{12}` that matches 12 to 14 digits with an optional plus symbol at the start.

**NOTE**: The regex is adjusted to the sample input you provided. If it is different, please adjust the limiting quantifiers `{12}` (that can be replaced with, say, `{9,14}` to match 9 to 14 occurrences of the quantified pattern).

Comment: be aware that your regex will catch: +00111111111111 , which is not one of the required cases

Comment: @Jumpa: Look at OP regexps, [they match the same](https://regex101.com/r/bB7cT7/1) and have no restrictions as for what the order of digits is or what digits can or cannot appear in the number. All I did was *merging* the patterns into a single one.